# Show content of a selected text file in a combox C#

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

```
private void ToonInhoud()
{
    string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
    string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.txt");
    foreach (string file in filePaths)
    {
        cboLanden.Items.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file));
    }
}

private void cboLanden_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

    StreamReader oSR = new StreamReader(path);

    String sLijn = oSR.ReadLine();

    while (sLijn != null)
    {
        string shops = sLijn;
        lstWinkels.Items.Add(shops);
        sLijn = oSR.ReadLine();
     }
     oSR.Close();
}
```

I have loaded 3 TEXT files in the first combobox and when 1 TEXT file is selected, I'd like to show the CONTENT in the Listbox using streamreader! So When you select TEXT file 1, i'd like the content of TEXT file 1 in the listbox, when I select TEXT file 2, I'd like the content of TEXT file 2 in the listbox, and so on.

Comment: Is it WPF? And what exactly you want to show in `lstWinkels` - whole file content? Should it be in one line, or not?

Comment: WPF yes, and just with +"\n" like on each line 1 word

Answer (score 0):

To add lines from selected files:

```
void cboLanden_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
   foreach(string fileName in e.AddedItems)
   {        
     string path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, fileName);

     foreach(string line in File.ReadLines(path))
        lstWinkels.Items.Add(line);
   }

   // handle RemovedItems
}
```

If you want to get whole content of selected file, use

```
string content = File.ReadAllText(path)
```

Comment: I'm assuming `lstWinkels` means that the data should be split across multiple list items. But apart from a `String.Split()` this seams the easiest approach :)

Comment: I have to learn to work with streamreader, is there any chance you can help me with my code? Using streamreader, the whole content of the selected file.

Comment: @user3173605 with StreamReader you can use `oSR.ReadToEnd()` to get all content. But `File.ReadAllText(path)` does exactly same behind the scene, so it would be better approach

Comment: I know, but I have to give the filename here: new StreamReader(path);
But the filename changes (3 txt files), how does it works then?

Comment: @user3173605 see my answer, you should use Path.Combine to create full path to file when you have directory path and file name

Comment: I get an error saying it cannot find the file path....belgie", but it's belgie.txt? How can I change this? Many thanks!